# Get the Index of elements in list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list `[4539, 5646, 6547, 7546]`.

How can i to get the index of every element ?

index of 4539 --> 0

index of 5646 --> 1

index of 6547 --> 2

index of 7546 --> 3

Comment: `elemIndex` or `elemIndices`? (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#g:16)

Comment: If you just want the elements packaged up with indices: `zip [0..] [4539, 5646, 6547, 7546]` => `[(0,4539),(1,5646),(2,6547),(3,7546)]`

Comment: Whatever problems this may have, it doesn't lack _focus_, which was the reason selected by all close voters.  Reopening.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- >> elemIndex 4539 [4539, 5646, 6547, 7546]
-- 0
-- >> elemIndex 5646 [4539, 5646, 6547, 7546]
-- 1
-- >> elemIndex 6547 [4539, 5646, 6547, 7546]
-- 2
elemIndex :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
```

What should happen when the element is not found?

```
>> elemIndex 20 []
*** Exception: elemIndex: empty list
```

The usual solution is to wrap the index in `Maybe`. This [`elemIndex` function exists in `Data.List`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:elemIndex).

```
-- >> elemIndex 4539 [4539, 5646, 6547, 7546]
-- Just 0
-- >> elemIndex 5646 [4539, 5646, 6547, 7546]
-- Just 1
-- >> elemIndex 6547 [4539, 5646, 6547, 7546]
-- Just 2
-- >> elemIndex 20 []
-- Nothing
elemIndex :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
```

Use [`elemIndices`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:elemIndices) if you want to return a list of occurrences.

```
-- >> elemIndices 'o' "ooookay"
-- [0,1,2,3]
elemIndices :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
```